# Join 2 datatables into one resultset

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have a dataset that contains 2 datatables they link together using a DataRelation.

it it possible to select from those tables into into one result set?

thanks,
Ofer

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft's suggestion is to create a helper class. See:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326080/en-us

This is a general purpose tool that can be used no matter what the source.

Answer (score 0):

You can create JOIN tables with the VS DataSet editor, whcih combine your results - you can then write Select queries against that and call them from within your app.

To do it, simply create a new TableAdapter, then add BOTH tables into the editor (use the visual one), and select the fields you want to use from both tables, then write the relevant select functions.